# I have to download volecity/mustache etc, Is there a simple way to start/use tile3?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles, tiles-3

for now I want to use tiles3 in struts2, I use this listener:

```
<listener>

    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>

</listener>
```

which lead me to download a lot of jar files: velocity, mustache etc.

those lib/jar I don't need in my project.

for performance and easy to use, is there a simple way to use tiles3 in struts2 ?

Comment: A simple google on the classname revealed this: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/BVumluCWGsOQ9fqcVUJ8 which suggests to use SimpleTilesListener. Very much "read the manual" stuff.

Comment: what's your keyword in google ?

Comment: the classname as I said; 'CompleteAutoloadTilesListener'

Comment: Not sure how this is a performance issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton If you never use velocity in your app why it's still requires it as dependency?

Comment: @RomanC http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tiles/tiles-extras/3.0.4/tiles-extras-3.0.4.pom

Comment: I think, the tiles3 is a bad design! if you want to "config" it, you have to do a lot of code instead of a config file! tiles is just a template system! why should it have to be so hard to use?